Is it possible to integrate a bulk and a pseudobulk (previously scRNA or snRNA seq) dataset
I have recently sequenced a bulk dataset. However one of my conditions has a lot of contamination from other cell types. I was thus thinking of using a publicly available single-cell dataset of my cell type of intereset, perform a pseudobulk reduction and integrate the pseudobulk dataset into my bulk RNA seq data.
Is this possible ? Or would there be way too much transcriptome variation and batch to batch differences ? Can I normalize for batch somehow?

No, you cannot. It is a basic principle of any experiment that you cannot add data from completely unrelated other experiments and expect any meaningful quantitative readout. There is a batch effect between the existing data and the newly-added public data, and since batch and experimental group is the same here you cannot correct for it. Don't do that.
